# Ethereum Go Source: hexToCompact function

Tags: go-ethereum, yellow-paper

I have a question regarding the following [code snippet](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/trie/encoding.go). Specifically the following function:

```
func hexToCompact(hex []byte) []byte {
    terminator := byte(0)
    if hasTerm(hex) {
        terminator = 1
        hex = hex[:len(hex)-1]
    }
    buf := make([]byte, len(hex)/2+1)
    buf[0] = terminator << 5 // the flag byte
    if len(hex)&1 == 1 {
        buf[0] |= 1 << 4 // odd flag
        buf[0] |= hex[0] // first nibble is contained in the first byte
        hex = hex[1:]
    }
    decodeNibbles(hex, buf[1:])
    return buf
}
```

This is a implementation of [Appendix-C Hex-Prefix encoding](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) from the Yellow Paper and when I did a search on this in the repo. I found a function within [slasher.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/d926bf2c7e3182d694c15829a37a0ca7331cd03c/trie/hasher.go) calls hexToCompact.

```
func (h *hasher) hashChildren(original node, db *Database) (node, node, error) {
    var err error

    switch n := original.(type) {
    case *shortNode:
        // Hash the short node's child, caching the newly hashed subtree
        collapsed, cached := n.copy(), n.copy()
        collapsed.Key = hexToCompact(n.Key)
        cached.Key = common.CopyBytes(n.Key)

        if _, ok := n.Val.(valueNode); !ok {
            collapsed.Val, cached.Val, err = h.hash(n.Val, db, false)
            if err != nil {
                return original, original, err
            }
        }
        return collapsed, cached, nil

    case *fullNode:
        // Hash the full node's children, caching the newly hashed subtrees
        collapsed, cached := n.copy(), n.copy()

        for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
            if n.Children[i] != nil {
                collapsed.Children[i], cached.Children[i], err = h.hash(n.Children[i], db, false)
                if err != nil {
                    return original, original, err
                }
            }
        }
        cached.Children[16] = n.Children[16]
        return collapsed, cached, nil

    default:
        // Value and hash nodes don't have children so they're left as were
        return n, original, nil
    }
}
```

My questions are

1. What is the need for Hex-Prefix compactness as specified in Yellow Paper?
2. What is **slasher.go** is trying to do here by compacting a shortnode and why just shortnode?.